# How to get a number within a specified range of a substring in python?

Tags: python, text-parsing

−3.7% [95% CI, −10.2% to 2.7%]; P = .26)

Above is an example of a string I'm using but I want to get all of the numbers in the string along with their classifiers i.e. the minus sign if it's negative, the % and the decimal point.

This string can change but the pattern for this string is consistent:

Primary Measure Value % [Confidence Interval% CI, CI Lower End% to CI Higher End%]; P= P Value)

Currently I'm using a code that pulls the numbers based on a specific index relative to substring "CI" and "P=" to pull this data but it's not 100% reliable since another string could have different number of digits and may or may not have negative numbers which means hard-coding an index number wouldn't pull the correct values.

Example of different string:

10.7% [95% CI, 1.2% to 12.7%]; P = .1)

I want to be able to assign the numeric values to the following variables including any negative signs, different digits of numbers, % sign and decimal sign.

Example of string and output desired:

```
string_1 = "10.7% [95% CI, 1.2% to 12.3%]; P = .1)"
```

**Desired Output**

Primary Measure Value is 10.7%

CI Lower End is 1.2%

CI Higher End is 12.3%

P Value is .1

```
string_2 = "−3.7% [95% CI, −10.2% to 2.7%]; P = .26)"
```

**Desired Output**

Primary Measure Value is -3.7%

CI Lower End is -10.2%

CI Higher End is 2.7%

P Value is .26

Is there a dynamic way to get the intended values of the above variables if all strings followed this same pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: okay here's a better solution doing it with a single regex call

```
import re

s = "−3.7% [95% CI, −10.2% to 2.7%]; P= .26)"
values = re.findall(r'([−.%\d]+)', s)
```

I use the regex module to extract the values for the desired output. The result is a list of strings containing your values.

Then you can do something like `print('Primary Measure Value is', values[0])` etc.

Comment: Out of curiosity: the second substitution isn't really necessary, right?

Comment: @BenjaminRuck There's probably a way to do it in one line, but honestly my regex skills are insufficient. The first substitution leaves multiple spaces between the desired groups and that would ruin the splits so I do a second substitution to compress the spaces.

Comment: Haha my regex skills aren't really good either, which is why I asked. `split()` will remove all spaces, no matter how many there are, so `"       a        b      c   ".split()` will return `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: @BenjaminRuck, Thanks - this almost solves it but right now the -3.7% is only showing up as 3.7% without the negative sign. 

Any idea how to include the negative sign for that number?

Comment: @ShubhamPandya sorry, I fixed it. I didn't realize the minus sign wasn't a simple dash. Should work now.